# Azure api management authentication link to web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

Our current API use seesionID for the authentication. We plan to use Azure API management to manage our web api. However Azure web api management has their own authentication. How can we link those two together. Our customer can use the same logon information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversations about authentication and identity in Azure API Management can get tricky because there can be three different identities and then there are the different contexts of runtime requests vs management requests.  So, to be sure I'm answering the right question, let me try and get some terms defined.

The three identities:

- **API Provider**: This is the Azure user who has created an API Management instance.
- **API Consumer**: This is a developer who is writing some client software to consume the API.
- **End User**:  The user of the application written by the API Consumer and will be the one who actually initiates runtime requests to the API.

I am assuming that you are the API Provider.  What I'm not sure about is whether your customers are the API Consumers or the End Users.

Azure API Management provides **identity services for API Consumers**.  Consumers can either manually create a username/password account or use some social identity provider to create an account.  They then can get a **subscription key** that will allow Azure API Management to associate requests to the API Consumer.

I think you are asking if you can connect the sessionID, which I am guessing you use to identify End Users, to a subscription key used to identify API Consumers.  If that is correct, then the answer is no (except for the scenario described below), because we need to identify the API Consumer key before any policies are run to ensure we run the correct policies.

You **can change our Api Consumer subscription key**. So, if you only have a low quantity of customers/End Users you could create an Api Consumer account for each End User. However, you would only be able to map sessionID to API Consumer Subscription Key if sessionID was a constant value.  I'm presuming based on the name, that value changes at each login.

Although Azure API Management **provides identity services of API Consumers**, it **does not provide full identity management for End Users**.  We leave that to external partners like Azure AD, Thinktecture Identity Server and Auth0.  I'm assuming that your existing system is already using some kind of identity provider to generate the sessionId.  What you can do with Azure API Management is **validate that sessionId using policies in the API Management Gateway**.  To do that we would need to know more about the format of the sessionId.

Sorry for the long post but it is a confusing topic and I wanted to be as clear as possible.